# Diffeomorphisms and conformal diffeomorphisms of Einstein spaces

Tags: geometry, diffeomorphism

Given $(M,g)$ with $M$ a manifold of dimension $d>2$ and $g$ an Einstein metric (that is $Ric[g]\propto g$) consider a diffeomorphism $\phi: M\rightarrow M$ such that $\phi^*g=g'$. Is $g'$ necessarily Einstein?

I know that if $\phi$ is a conformal diffeomorphism, the conformal factor must satisfy some specific properties for the resulting metric $\phi^*g$ to be Einstein.

Comment: If two metrics are isometric and one is Einstein, then so is the other.

Comment: So the answer to the question is no in general? According to the definition I know, $\phi$ is an isometry if $\phi^*g=g$, but in general a diffeomorphism gives $\phi^*g=g'$ with $g'$ different from $g$.

Comment: To the contrary, the answer is always positive, since $\phi$ is an isometry  $(M,g')\to (M,g)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.